# How do you replace pre-entered characters (one at a time) in the JTextField?

Tags: java, character-replacement

I am trying to create a text field that at first contains only underscores and dashes, in which the user will enter numbers, for entering social security numbers. Every time the user enters a character, the underscore in the string will be replaced with that number, for example, ***___***-***__***-***____*** then xxx-***__***-***____***, xxx-xx-***____***, but the dashes will not be replaced, instead skipped over.I'm really stuck on this, and any help at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JFormattedTextField`. For details go through this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).